# Reputation required for privileges

Tags: discussion, reputation

How come the reputation required for participating in close votes, accepting edits etc. has been raised to 3k ? I was enjoying helping out on these, and there are not so many members with 3k+ reputation.

Comment: Well, that is due to graduation, where the reputation limits are higher than on the beta sites. I believe, this will make the transition for the moderator a little bit harder, since there are less user with the appropriate privileges, and raising flags will probably increase.

Comment: The "graduated" totals can be found [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/). Hopefully, the increasing traffic will lead to increasing votes and make it easier to move up.

Comment: But keep it up and you'll break 3k in no time at all. :-)

Comment: Okay, thanks  !  didn't even realize we were in beta....

Comment: _I crossed 1k and they changed it :/_

Answer (score 6):

To make clear from the comments, we were previously a "beta" site, which has lower point totals required for different privilege levels.

We graduated, which gives us a shiny new design, and bunch of related features.

The new point totals required can be found [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/).

Comment: *Cracks knuckles* - got some work to do :)

Comment: @santiago Indeed. We all do. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Among the cheering, there was the sound of the global Chem.SE community cracking knuckles (*I think the USGS got nervous*), as graduation moves the threshold goal-posts further, the hard working community has stepped up to meet the challenge!